# Acceder a array en $parent AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estoy tratando acceder a una propiedad de $parent, la cuál es un array y no puedo recuperarla.

Si accedo, de la misma forma, a una variable String, no hay problema en mostrarla.

Necesitaría saber como recuperar ese valor del array completo.

Accedo de la siguiente manera desde el controlador

```
$scope.$parent.string
```

En este no hay problema, me escribe el nombre

Pero al acceder

```
$scope.$parent.array
```

Me devuelve undefined

Comment: Ya solucioanste el problema? te puedo ayudar?

Comment: No, sigo con el mismo error

Comment: Solucionado, en las pruebas, era error mío, veía el json sin cargarlo

Comment: ok que bien, saludos